# Why are redundant parenthesis not allowed in syntax definitions?

Tags: rascal

This syntax module is syntactically valid:

```
module mod1

syntax Empty =

;
```

And so is this one, which should be an equivalent grammar to the previous one:

```
module mod2 

syntax Empty =
   ( ) 
;
```

(The resulting parser accepts only empty strings.)

Which means that you can make grammars such as this one:

```
module mod3 

syntax EmptyOrKitchen =
   ( ) | "kitchen"
;
```

But, the following is not allowed (nested parenthesis):

```
module mod4 

syntax Empty =
   (( )) 
;
```

I would have guessed that redundant parenthesis are allowed, since they are allowed in things like expressions, e.g. `((2)) + 2`.

---

This problem came up when working with the data types for internal representation of rascal syntax definitions. The following code will create the same module as in the last example, namely `mod4` (modulo some whitespace):

```
import Grammar;
import lang::rascal::format::Grammar;
str sm1 = definition2rascal(\definition("unknown_main",("the-module":\module("unknown",{},{},grammar({sort("Empty")},(sort("Empty"):prod(sort("Empty"),[
                                  alt({seq([])})
                                                ],{})))))));
```

The problematic part of the data is on its own line - `alt({seq([])})`. If this code is changed to `seq([])`, then you get the same syntax module as `mod2`. If you further delete this whole expression, i.e. so that you get this:

```
str sm3 = 
definition2rascal(\definition("unknown_main",("the-module":\module("unknown",{},{},grammar({sort("Empty")},(sort("Empty"):prod(sort("Empty"),[

                                   ], {})))))));
```

Then you get `mod1`.

So should such redundant parenthesis by printed by the `definition2rascal(...)` function? And should it matter with regards to making the resulting module valid or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why they are not allowed is basically we wanted to see if we could do without. There is currently no priority relation between the symbol kinds, so in general there is no need to have a bracket syntax (like you do need to + and * in expressions).

Already the brackets have two different semantics, one `()` being the *epsilon* symbol and two `(Sym1 Sym2 ...)` being a nested sequence. This nested sequence is defined (syntactically) to expect at least two symbols. Now we could without ambiguity introduce a third semantics for the brackets with a single symbol or relax the requirement for sequence... But we reckoned it would be confusing that in one case you would get an extra layer in the resulting parse tree (sequence), while in the other case you would not (ignored superfluous bracket).

More detailed wise, the problem of printing `seq([])` is not so much a problem of the meta syntax but rather that the backing abstract notation is more relaxed than the concrete notation (i.e. it is a bigger language or an over-approximation). The parser generator will generate a working parser for `seq([])`. But, there is no Rascal notation for an empty sequence and I guess the pretty printer should throw an exception.

Comment: I'm interested to hear what you think about this. If you want we could discuss it on the issues tracker at github. It's not a stackoverflow discussion IMHO.